# Apply dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to a bunch of UIImageViews not TableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Im not sure if this is possible but I was just hoping to have a question answered about  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and if it could be applied to something other than a `UITableViewCell`. Maybe not `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` exactly, but maybe something along the same idea.

I have a bunch of `UIImageViews`, that appear in a grid, they all have the same image, and the user can remove and add more to the grid so it is quite dynamic. But I was hoping that maybe there would be a way to reuse some of the images that the user has removed, because I'm seeing some pretty large performance issues after the user interacts with them for a little while.

Can anyone give me a little advice how I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in mechanism, but it's not hard to create one.

Just add an NSMutableArray to your view controller. Every time you remove a view from the grid because it's moved off screen add it to the array. Every time you need to add a new view to the grid, check the array and see if there are any views in it. If there are, remove one from the array and add it to the screen. If there aren't, create alloc a new view.

That's really all there is to view dequeing and re-use.

You don't need to replicate the reuseIdentifier stuff because (I'm guessing) all the views in your grid will be the same class.

If you do need to have multiple different views, just have multiple queue arrays and use different arrays for different view types.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create one `UITableViewCell` & add 2 `ImageViews` on them. Dont forget to add a unique cell identifier to them o that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` works as usual.

Something like this -

[image]